# Yarn capacity-scheduler Parallelize

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

Does capacity-scheduler in yarn run app in parallel on the same queue for the same user.

For example:If we have 2 hive CLI on 2 terminals with same user, and the same query is started on both, do they execute on the default queue in parallel or sequentially.

Currently, the UI shows 1 running, and 1 in pending state:

[image]

Is there a way to run it in parallel?

Comment: check for  yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-applications /
    yarn.scheduler.capacity.<queue-path>.maximum-applications properties (https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html) and let me know if it works

Comment: <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-applications</name>
    <value>10000</value>
    </property> it has been this since start, so that parameter does not help

Answer (score 0):

Yarn capacity scheduler run jobs in FIFO manner for the jobs submitted in the same queue. For example if both the hive cli's got submitted for default queue then which ever able to secure resources first will get into running state and other will wait(only if enough resources are not present in the queue).

If you want parallel execution 
1) you can run other job in different queue.You can define the queue name while launching job on yarn.
2) You need to define resources in a manner so that both job can get resources as desired.